# rxjs, recursively call api until all items are fetched

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to call an api and fetch all items from an endpoint. However we can only fetch 100 items at a time.

The response looks like this:

```
{
    elements: Array<any>,
    totalCount: number,
}
```

and the endpoint would be `/api/items?drop=${drop}&take=100` with `drop` being used to paginate.

I think that would involve the scan and takeWhile operators somewhere.. Here is what I got:

```
    const subject = new Subject();
    const rec = subject.pipe(
        scan((acc: number, curr: number) => (curr + 100), 0),
        switchMap(drop => this.http.get(`api/items?drop=${drop}&take=100`)),
        takeWhile((r: any) => r.elements.length === 100),
        tap(r => subject.next())
    );
```

Comment: Do you know how many items there will be ?

Comment: just return no of records form the API and increment until that no

Comment: @Antoniossss no I don't know the amount of items

Comment: use a variable "page" (take values 0,1,2,...), then ask about from page*100 to (page+1)*100-1, or use a slice(page*100,(page+1)*100)

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-expand-a5f8b41a3602

Comment: The above link is no longer valid. The canonical link to the blog post is: https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-expand/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to know how many elements will be returned, just how many it will never be :)

```js
Observable.range(0, 1000000).pipe(
  concatMap(page => this.http.get(`api/items?drop=${page * take}&take=${take}`))
  takeWhile(results => results.elements.length === take)
)
```

At first I thought using `range` as source would pile up the requests and defeat the purpose of paging, but concatMap gives automatic throttling.

From [learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)

> Note the difference between concatMap and mergeMap. Because concatMap does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous completes, the value from the source delayed by 2000ms will be emitted first. Contrast this with mergeMap which subscribes immediately to inner observables, the observable with the lesser delay (1000ms) will emit, followed by the observable which takes 2000ms to complete.

Here's a test of ***concatMap***, which shows `getPage` is not called until the previous results emit

```js
const take = 100;
const getPage = (page) => {
  console.log('reading page', page);
  return Rx.Observable.of(page).delay(1000);
}

Rx.Observable.range(0,3)
  .concatMap(getPage)
  .subscribe(results => console.log('concatMap results', results));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.10/Rx.js"></script>
```

Contrast with ***mergeMap***, which makes all calls to `getPage` immediately

```js
const take = 100;
const getPage = (page) => {
  console.log('reading page', page);
  return Rx.Observable.of(page).delay(1000);
}

Rx.Observable.range(0,3)
  .mergeMap(getPage)
  .subscribe(results => console.log('mergeMap results', results));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.10/Rx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I got it working by using an external variable but it's not really pretty...

```
const take = 100;
const subject = new BehaviorSubject(0);
// var used for pagination
let i = 0;
const rec = subject.pipe(
    map((acc: number) => (acc * 100)),
    switchMap(drop => this.http.get(`api/items?drop=${drop}&take=${take}`)),
    map((r: any) => r.elements),
    tap(items=> {
        if (items.length === take)
            subject.next(++i);
    })
);
return rec;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps :)

I would go with something simpler, the subscription is a bit imperative but I guess we can sacrifice fanciness for readability. You should probably think about errors and retries as this is clearly just the happy path

```
const subject = new Subject();
const createUrl = (drop = 0) => `api/items?drop=${drop}&take=100`
const fetchApi = url => Observable.fromPromise(fetch(url))

const requestItems = (pagination = 0) => {
    fetchApi(createUrl(pagination))
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(response => {
        if(response.elements.length === 100) {
            requestItems(pagination++)
        }
        subject.next(response)
    })
}

requestItems()
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake somewhere there. In the subscribe you are doing subject.next. However said subject isn't used anywhere, unless i missed something ?

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating the suggestion of @cartant, you could address your need without having to rely on a Subject but rather using the `expand` operator, along the lines of the following snippet

```
let counterOfItemsFetched = 0;
function api() {
    // console.log('counterOfItemsFetched', counterOfItemsFetched)
    return counterOfItemsFetched < 1000 ? 100 : 1;
}

function apiAsynCall() {
    return Observable.of(api()).delay(1000);
}

Observable.of(0).pipe(
    expand(() => apiAsynCall().pipe(tap(itemsFetched => counterOfItemsFetched = counterOfItemsFetched + itemsFetched))),
    filter(counter => counter > 0),
    tap(() => console.log(counterOfItemsFetched)),
    takeWhile(counter => counter ===  100),
)
.subscribe(
    null,
    null,
    () => console.log('counter value at the end', counterOfItemsFetched)
)
```